# Insert order using webservice with OpenERP

Tags: php, xml-rpc, odoo

I have an e-commerce website (PHP). I want to insert orders into OpenERP when I have order in my e commerce website. I found openerp support XML-RPC to do (https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/#php-example). But I want to know exactly how to do it, because in document I don't find function to do it. I must insert directly to openerp 's database or openerp already have function to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function to do it via XML-RPC.  You have to talk to the objects (aka tables such as `sales.order`) in order to retrieve existing orders or add new ones.

Comment: I afraid of when we want add new order not only insert sales.order but also insert data to some another table. But I can't find any database structure doccument of openerp.

Answer (score 0):

[ERPpeek](https://github.com/tinyerp/erppeek) is an excellent tool to get a better grasp of Odoo's XML-RPC interface. You can interactively (Python) try to insert orders and it will report back the problem if something is wrong.

Comment: I noticed that you're adding the odoo tag to openerp questions. Why not just make the tags synonyms? I've proposed the synonym on the [openerp tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/openerp/synonyms). Vote for it if you agree.

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. And I can't actually do that, it's saying "You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym". And it looks like it will take a whole while before I can do that since it takes 2k5 rep.

Comment: What to do until we have this tag synonymity? Add [odoo] or not? I think it makes sense to move towards the use of "Odoo" and deprecate ÖpenERP" for new questions. Should this be a meta question? :)

Comment: Sure, create a meta question and link to it from here. I haven't been using OpenERP for a year, so I don't have any rep in the `odoo` tag to make `openerp` a synonym of `odoo`. You could look at the top users for that tag, and leave a comment on one of their answers with a link to your meta question.

Comment: From all the [Odoo] questions it looks like you're the only even with 2k5+ rep, so it looks like it can take years before this tag synonym can ever happen.

Comment: Asked a question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267136/is-there-a-shortcut-for-tag-synonymity-when-a-software-project-has-been-renamed

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that i created so far to insert a new order to a certain customer using xmlrpc.Here is the code if it helps anything now.

```
function createNewOrder($params,$model_name)
{
    $client = new xmlrpc_client($this->server . "object");
    $client->return_type = 'phpvals';

    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');

    $nval = array();
    foreach($params as $k=>$v){
        $nval[$k] = new xmlrpcval( $v, xmlrpc_get_type($v) );
    }

    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->database, "string"));  //* database name */
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->uid, "int")); /* useid */
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));
    /** password */
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($model_name, "string"));
    /** model name where operation will held * */
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
    /** method which u like to execute */
   // $msg->addParam(xmlrpc_encode($params));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($nval, "struct"));/** parameters of the methods with values....  */

    // $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($nval, "struct"));

    /** parameters of the methods with values....  */

    $resp = $client->send($msg);

    if ($resp->errno != 0)
        trigger_error("sock_execute error " . $resp->errstr);

    return xmlrpc_decode($resp->value());
}
```

How to use it:

```
  $order = array(     
    'partner_id'=> 9
);

$objekti = new OpenERP();
$OERPUserID = $objekti->login($_SESSION['OERP-username'], $_SESSION['OERP-password']);
$order_id =$objekti->createNewOrder($order, 'sale.order' );
```

But I'm having trouble adding products in this order, but as soon as i finish that part I'll edit my post.